# Angular 2 post method gives typescript error

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angular-services

I am using Angular 2 And I interact with an API through a service.
I have a method that I want to use for posting into the API.

> ERROR in src/app/application/users/create-new-user/create-new-user.component.ts(146,5): error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

```
user.ts code

var submitData =
{
  first_name: formData.firstName,
  last_name: formData.lastName,
  email: formData.email,
  password: formData.password,
  address_1: formData.address1,
  address_2: formData.address2,}

his.appService.createUser(submitData).subscribe((result: any) => {
  if (result != '') {
```

appservice.ts

```
createUser(): Observable<any> {

  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('security-token', localStorage.getItem('loginToken'));

  return this.http.post<any>(this.basePath + '/user-groups', { headers })
    .pipe(
      map((response => {
        return response.data;
      }))
```

Comment: Add some code so that the community can help you

Comment: add some code.

your service may be expecting some args but you arenot providing them while calling

Comment: According to the info you provided so far, you gave somewhere in your code an argument to a method that doesn't take any.

Comment: @AdritaSharma can u help

Comment: @AmeerPappay i use arguments

Comment: can you post appService.createUser code . you might have forgot the argument in that function.

Comment: @DimuthuMaduranga You should be having the parameter in the function's definition. In your  app.service.ts, `createUser()` should have the argument that refers to your `submitData`

Comment: In createUser() Code that you have mentioned , You are returning response.data which is not Observable type, If you are returning Observable type from service You should not use Pipe there. Just Write : return this.http.post(this.basePath + '/user-groups', { headers }) And also consider the argument being passed so the function must be defined like createUser(data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Many Mistakes in the Code Mentioned. I will Point them out as per relevance.
1.Argument Passed Must be defined in createUser Function.
2.You are only setting header and not passing any data in the POST request which is your main purpose.
3. You must not return response.data instead just return output of the POST method as the return type of createUser is Observable .

So the Correct way to write the Code must be :

createUser(data:any): Observable {

const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('security-token', localStorage.getItem('loginToken'));

return this.http.post(this.basePath + '/user-groups', data, {headers: headers})
}

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

user.ts

```
  submitData() {

    var submitData =
    {
      first_name: formData.firstName,
      last_name: formData.lastName,
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password,
      address_1: formData.address1,
      address_2: formData.address2,
    }
    this.appService.createUser(submitData).subscribe((result: any) => {
      if (result != '') {
        console.log(result)
      }
    })
  }
```

appservice.ts

```
 createUser(data:any): Observable<any> {


    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('security-token', localStorage.getItem('loginToken'));

    return this.http.post(this.basePath + '/user-groups', data, { headers })
  }
```